# How to make JTable process only the movement keys?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keystrokes

I have a Form constructed dynamically, and the components added register keys they need to process actions.
It have a JTable too, and when the JTable is focused, it is processing all the keys, so keys configured to trigger actions on the other components arent being executed.
Can I configure the Jtable to only process the movement keys? e.g. arrows, home, end, pg up and down, etc?

Edit 1:
The JFrame containing the other components is using this function to register de key bindings:

```
  private void addActionListener(final int key_, final ActionListener al_){
    getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(al_,
                                     KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key_, 0),
                                     JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
  }
```

When the focus is in any component but the JTable, the registered keys triggers accordingly, but when the focus is in the JTable, the key appears to be *"trapped"* in the JTable

If this isnt yet enought, I will be doing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and will edit again later.

Comment: We don't know how you are actually registering the keys. You should be using a Key Bindings. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr), when I was doing the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) I understood the problem: the key I was testing my program was *F2*, and it is used by the JTable to edit a cell.
My original program dont have cell edition, and this wasnt so clear to see in it. 
Anyway, a strange behaviour is that other keys used by JTable can be bind, and, after being used by the JTable, they are processed for the keybinding registered - but not the F2.